# Positioning the Popup in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am having a hard time to position the popup on a specified position. Here is my code and for some reason it never displays at the specified coordinates.

```
$("#overlay").popup({
    transition: "slideup",
    shadow: false,
    corners: false,
    beforeposition: function (event, ui) {
        ui.x = 0;
        ui.y = 100;
    }
}).popup("open");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `$(this).css` :

- **HTML:**

  ```
  <div id="overlay" data-role="popup" data-tolerance="0">
  </div>
  ```
- **JS:**

  ```
  $(document).on("pagecreate", function (event, ui) {
      $("#overlay").popup({
          transition: "slideup",
          shadow: false,
          corners: false,
          beforeposition: function (event, ui) {
              $(this).css({
                  left: 0,
                  top: 100
              });
          }
      });
  });
  ```

Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rosberglinhares/hds1pkqg/).